# Facebook Limitations Breakdown, the absolute facts

Tags: php, facebook, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the Facebook's Graph API call limit?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8713241/whats-the-facebooks-graph-api-call-limit)

I have heard from several sources, most of which are stack overflow or other well reputed web portals telling me that there is a limit of 600 api calls per 600 seconds to facebook api.  I personally think its more then that, but exactly where that line is seems to vary and I have no idea really what to put my finger on.

The catch:

I have also heard that its 600 api calls per 600 seconds per access code.

I have also heard that its 600 api calls per 600 seconds per ip address, per code.

I have also heard that its 600 api calls per 600 seconds per ip address only.

My question to you is, which one is it?